# Is a taste test a reliable way to determine mineral deficiencies?

Tags: nutrition, minerals, deficiency, taste

I stumbled across a rather odd class of products online, dubbed "trace mineral taste test kits". I won't link to them because it'll probably trigger all the spam filter bots, but a typical product description is as follows (emphasis mine):

> Set Contains: 8 - 8 oz bottles Liquid Mineral Test
>
> 1. Potassium
> 2. Zinc
> 3. Magnesium
> 4. Copper
> 5. Chromium
> 6. Manganese
> 7. Molybdenum
> 8. Selenium
>
> To Test - Sip a small portion. Swish the liquid about the mouth, you may discard or swallow. The mg. Content of each mineral per taste test is insignificant.
>
> **You need this mineral if the taste is sweet, pleasant or no taste. You have an adequate amount of the mineral if you taste something. You don't need this mineral if the taste is so-so, you don't like it, or it's pretty bad.**

At a glance this seems to be a bit of pseudo-science to me. On the other hand I do know that e.g. food tastes better when I'm hungry, water tastes better when I'm thirsty, etc.

Is this based in truth? Are mineral deficiencies, at least the ones in that list, self-identifiable based on the "pleasantness" of the taste? I'm primarily looking for answers backed by concrete, peer-reviewed studies from reliable sources.